# Why is this jQuery not sliding down/showing hidden (slid up) elements?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I create rows with IDs of foapalrow3 and foapalrow4 in C#, making them temporarily invisible:

```
foapalrow3 = new HtmlTableRow();
foapalrow3.ID = "foapalrow3";
. . .
foapalrow3.Visible = false;

foapalrow4 = new HtmlTableRow();
foapalrow4.ID = "foapalrow4";
. . .
foapalHTMLTable.Rows.Add(foapalrow4);
foapalrow4.Visible = false;
```

I then have jQuery to condtionally make this visible again:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnAddFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    if ($('[id$=foapalrow3]').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('[id$=foapalrow3]').slideDown();
    } else if ($('[id$ = foapalrow4]').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('[id$=foapalrow4]').slideDown();
    }
});
```

...but it doesn't work - the rows are still not shown. Is it that "visible == false" in C# does not match "display == none" in jQuery, or what?

Comment: This might be informative: [Question regarding Visible=false and display:none;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907422/question-regarding-visible-false-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check for the display property using

```
$('[id$=foapalrow4]').is(":visible");
```